# How to show the activityindicator while uploading image on facebook from iphone?

Tags: image, facebook, upload, facebook-graph-api

Am using FbGraph and SBJSON files for uploading images on facebook from iphone. A white window is stay in application while image uploading on facebook, i want to show the Progressview or uiactivityindicator on that time. I tried for my level best, but its not responding. Where am wrong, how can i show the activity indicator while image upload on facebook...... Any one have an idea for this problem....

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Graph api for uploading images on Facebook wall from iphone application, UIWebview is stands for sometime while image uploading on Facebook. If you don't want that blank white space on the screen you just Remove the webview and show the UIActivityIndicator view on the moment. Really its work for me. Try it now. Otherwise just hidden the webview and show the activityindicator view, in this method dont forget to release the webview and activityindicator after image uploaded on the Facebook wall.

Cheers!
Yuva.M

Comment: what this Cheers ? lol.... asked questn thanks in advance... and answered own by cheers.. u must be a very funny guy

Answer (score 0):

I just find the solution for the "Blank White Screen" during the Login Process.
We have to change in the FBGraph.m file.

In this method `authenticateUserWithCallbackObject` we have to add one line.

```
[aWebView setHidden:YES];
```

then this problem will be solved.